# Unusual link creation issue

Tags: php, html, css

I have a header bar that I am trying to create a link in. This website was created by another company before I was brought on board. I'm not a complete beginner when it comes to HTML but this has stumped me. I created a link for a page on the header bar. The page is called gallery.php. The link points to gallery.php, which is in the same directory as the other pages. When you press the link, it says that the page cannot be found, when the page is obvioulsy in the same directory. I also want to point out that the page uses twitters bootstrap framework.

Here is the HTML for the header:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
<meta name="author" content="Lewis Precision, Inc.">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />

<link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/116311092915765331437"/>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Note+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<body>

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>     <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a style="color:#CDD3DA" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>
    <!--<li><a style="color:#CDD3DA" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>-->

    <!-- Services 
        <li><a style="color:#CDD3DA" href="precision-cnc-milling-services">Services</a></li> 
        -->
    <li><a style="color:#CDD3DA" href="industries-served">Industries</a></li>
    <li><a style="color:#CDD3DA" href="precision-cnc-equipment">Equipment</a></li>
    <!--<li><a style="color:#CDD3DA" href="gallery">Gallery</a></li>-->
    <li><a style="color:#CDD3DA" href="meet-the-staff">Staff</a></li>
    <li><a style="color:#CDD3DA" href="contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

Im sorry that it is a little convoluted. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do the other links work? Are they individual files (i.e. contact.php / contact.html)? And if so, what file extension do they have?

Comment: They have an extension of .php. Yes, the other links work, which is why its a little strange that this particular link won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is looking for a folder called `/gallery/` not a page called `gallery.php`

```
<li><a style="color:#CDD3DA" href="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
```

You'll either need to create a folder of that name, rename the `gallery.php` to `index.php` and place it within this folder.

OR

Change the link to `gallery.php`

Comment: I actually did that, and it still did the same thing. I had actually named it gallery.php and it still did the same thing. The other files are in the same directory, and they are only referenced as "Home" an so on. Is there something Im missing?

Comment: check the .htaccess to see if they're being pointed to the new file?

Comment: Now, i know how to access the .htaccess, but do you put that file individually into the .htaccess? Would it help for me to post the.htaccess file?

Comment: search the `htaccess` for `.php` and see if you can find anything.

Comment: you'd be looking for some sort of `mod_rewrite`

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: Sorry, enter posts to the forum. These are the only 2 that were in there. There is not a mod_rewrite rule. I appreciate you folks helping me, this is a really strange situation.